# regarding types of web applications in general

Tags: html, web-applications, static

Are there static web applications where they only have HTML pages which are static? If there are, can you please provide some practical examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your definitions of static and dynamic.  It's possible to have a web application where the original downloaded HTML is static, then the DOM is manipulated in the browser using JavaScript and AJAX callbacks, but I'd probably still describe this as 'dynamic' web application.

Answer (score 1):

No, by definition, a web application has to be dynamic.